# Beginner Tutorial for CakePHP 2.1?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.1

I was just wondering if any one knew of any good beginner tutorials for CakePHP 2.1 other than the ones on their site (the cakephp book/ blog tutorial)?

Comment: Informative http://webdesignergeeks.com/coding/php/getting-start-with-cakephp-beginner-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular tutorial that I've seen is the blog tutorial. It is relevant for the version you specified.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

It's very easy to understand and follow.

Answer (score 4):

For you :D

http://devmoose.com/coding/10-awesome-cakephp-tutorials

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately these tutorials aren't for CakePHP 2.1, they are for versions around CakePHP 1.2-1.3